# Were Gary and Wyatt scienc-ey in a non-weird way?

Tags: weird-science

It's clear from the film that Gary Wallace and Wyatt Donnelly are dorks.

But the title of the film is "Weird **Science**", which implies that they were doing "science".

Is there any evidence in canon that they were indeed "sciencey" geeky type of characters; as opposed to random dorks with low social skills but no specific above-normal "science" interest which is how they seemed to me?

<sub>(No, I do not think that putting a bra on one's head makes one a scientist)</sub>

Comment: According to the Wikipedia summary (yes, I've seen the film, but that was decades ago) it involves electrodes.  That sounds like science to me.

Comment: There was also a TV series; http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108988/

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I could link you to distinctly non-sciency use of electrodes but I am not certain the site's PG-13 rating would be compatible with said link.

Comment: “I do not think that putting a bra on one's head makes one a scientist” — huh. Guess I might as well take this one off then.

Comment: "No, I do not think that putting a bra on one's head makes one a scientist".  You, sir, clearly don't know how to science.

Comment: @WadCheber - I'll file a complaint with my college over clearly deficient teaching plans.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - Show them [this](http://i.imgur.com/X7Mr8Mf.jpg)

Comment: Weren't their names Gary and Wyatt?  Gary's last name is Wallace and Wyatt's last name is Donnelly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wyatt certainly was. He has **science books** (including '[The Book of Popular Science](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTA3NFgxNjAw/z/tvkAAOSw-vlVgxf7/$_1.JPG)' and '[Principles of Toxicology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0873716841)'), resource materials (editions of '[Byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_(magazine))', 'Robotics Ace' and 'Modern Electronics') and a selection of science provisions that suggest a deep and abiding interest in scientific research, especially in relation to biology, electronics and computing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Like all good scientists, Wyatt has **a calculator watch**

[image]

**An interest in astronomy**

[image]

**Electronics equipment**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What was the last picture supposed to be an illustration of?

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - Electronics equipment (namely crocodile clips)

Comment: In context, the doll has become a piece of science equipment.

Comment: Alligator clips*

Comment: @WadCheber - It's not spelled valor, it's not pronounced 'vase' [vais] and these are **crocodile** clips.